# Explanations for differences between internet bandwith measurements with MikroTik and local clients

Tags: networking, windows-10, internet, bandwidth, mikrotik-routeros

**Problem:**

I am using an internet provider offering a symmetrical gigabit internet.
Recently I noticed a marked slow-down of my internet connection (up around max. 50 Mbps and down around max. 100 Mbps, LAN). A few months ago, I reached speeds around 900/950 with exactly the same hardware/software setting.

For debugging, my provider sent me a new fiber patch cable and a certified, gigabit capable router.

I repeated the speed measurements according to the manual of my provider:
https://www.init7.net/en/support/faq/speedtest/ using https://init7.speedtest.net/
with 3 Win10 clients and 1 Ubuntu 19.1 client connected to the new router and fiber cable. All firewalls and anti-virus software were turned off during testing. All of the clients have gigabit capable hardware). I still could not reach better speeds.

For further debugging, my provider sent me a new fiber patch cable and a MikroTik router (CCR1009-8G-1S-1S+, RouterOS v6.39.2) and made remote speed measurements directly on the MikroTik router. They reported speeds around 900/900 Mbps directly on the MikroTik. I also made some measurements on the MikroTik:

```
status: running
duration: 40s
rx-current: 973.0Mbps
rx-10-second-average: 974.5Mbps
rx-total-average: 996.7Mbps
lost-packets: 31407
random-data: no
direction: receive
rx-size: 1500
```

I also repeated my the speed measurements with my clients connected directly to the MikroTik, resulting in the same, slow speeds as with the router from my provider.

Now my provider states, that my local client is causing a slow-down of the internet bandwith.
I really doubt that there is something wrong with my local clients.

During debugging I opened the MikroTik Log and found a lot of login failures:

```
login failure for user admin from 107.189.11.193 via ssh
```

I instantly contacted my provider and they told me that the security setting of their MikroTik was not well set. They told me that they fixed it. However, I got many new login failures in the log since then.

**Question:**

1. Is there any possible explanation for the differences between the internet bandwith measured with the MikroTik and local clients?
2. Is it normal that I get so many login failures on my MikroTik?

Comment: Are you running with the def con setup? I would add ports 22,80,8291 to a drop rule if not from a source address list. This may or may not be causing the speed slowness depends on the frequency of the port checking but still needs to be locked down

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not very familiar with the MikroTik and my provider only gave me a guest account with read rights for it so I think I cannot change the drop rules. However, do you think this could be linked to the speed slowness with my normal router (Asus RT-AC87U)? I get the same slow speeds if I measure it directly with the MikroTik or directly my own Asus router.

Comment: Would this also affect the speed measurements done directly on the MikroTik? I made some measurements by myself and the speed was always quite high.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/gVoaJny that is the setting I found

Comment: “However, I got many new login failures in the log since then.” Any device connected to the Internet will have a flood of failed login attempts. This is the nature of the internet world in 2020. It’s constant bot login attempts. This should utterly never affect bandwidth in any way. And should not be a concern to you… Unless of course you left your admin password on the router as a default password… Then you should be worried! But otherwise, your ISP was most likely lying to you since there is no security setting that can prevent failed login attempts.

Comment: @JakeGould thank you for your answer. Nope, luckly my ISP does not use a default password fot the admin login. So Q2 is sovled for me. But I am still wondering about Q1... Think my ISP is not lying about the speedtest on the MikroTik since I also made some with good results.

Comment: 1, Your router needs an update, any mikrotik router before 6.42rc27 is vulnerable to an unauthenticated buffer overflow attack. 2. @JakeGould is correct and there is no setting to block after x attempts but there is a lot of filter rules out there to block the port scanners before any authentication can happen from a bot. I would not be using this router in its current state if you like your security and your ISP should not be sending out routers with this configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Just promptly disconnected the router! This is actually quite frightening. I just got an email from my ISP today ensuring that everything is save with their MikroTik and that I should not worry about the safety. Do you think Q2 could somehow be linked to the number of lost-packages I posted above?

Comment: @captcoma no it shouldnt be. when you're speed testing on the mikrotik what server are you testing and is it the same server you're testing on the clients machines?

Comment: @SQLTemp I use the server that is recommended by my ISP (https://init7.speedtest.net/) and yes, I use the same server for the speed testing on the clients machines.

Comment: @captcoma You are panicking. There is really nothing you can do to prevent scans and attempted login attacks from bots. Every single publicly exposed IP address in the world is subjected to this kind of stuff. Just make sure you changed the admin password on the router and that’s that. The customer service rep at your ISP is really lying and trying to appease you; they don’t know what they are talking about.

Comment: I see. But @SQLTemp's hint regarding update was very important. I still wonder about Q2.

Comment: I mean Q1 is still open.